# Ajax, Javascript, or Database for post/get results

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, database

I have a question about what backend to use.  I have a html page that has various dropdown lists.  On Submit I want to sent the results of that page to another page to compile the (average) results.  Is there a way to do this without setting up a database?  I was thinking of sending the data with Ajax and then compiling the data with Javascript on the receiving page.

I've done something like this before so any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Yes it is possible. A page say "A.html" will make the url with necessary parameters and pass it to another page say "B.html". Page "B.html" will get the parameters in javascript and compute the result and show it to the necessary place. It would be helpful if you post some codes what you've tried

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use jquery to check the changes in the dropdown list. Send the results to a jquery ajax page and get the return value as json. The result json can be shown on the same page with jquery.

Comment: That's essentially what I was thinking!  Wow I might actually know something.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I assume the page you are talking about is an html or jsp page. Yes you can use javascript ot process the data and then send it to a servlet and get it back to another jsp.